# Rails 5 pdf preview with Shrine Gem

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, shrine

I am using [Shrine Gem](http://shrinerb.com/) for image uploads and was wondering how, if possible, can I show a 1st page preview in my template like showing an image per-say.  I am ok with using jQuery or other library.  Below is my code for the file upload, including my Shrine initializer and uploader file.

**view**

```
...
<div class="col-md-4 upload-block">
    <%= f.label :spec_sheet, 'Spec Sheet' %>
      <% if @product.spec_sheet.present? %>
        <div class="product-image">
          <%= image_tag(@product.spec_sheet_url(:thumb)) %>
            <div class="input-checkbox input-checkbox--switch">
              <input name="product[remove_spec_sheet]" type="hidden" value="0">
              <input id="checkbox-switch" type="checkbox" name="product[remove_spec_sheet]">
              <label for="checkbox-switch"></label>
            </div>
            <span>Remove Spec Sheet</span>
        </div>
        <% end %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :spec_sheet, value: @product.cached_spec_sheet_data %>
            <%= f.file_field :spec_sheet %>
  </div>
...
```

**initializer**

```
require 'shrine'
require 'shrine/storage/file_system'

Shrine.storages = {
    cache: Shrine::Storage::FileSystem.new('public', prefix: 'uploads/cache'),
    store: Shrine::Storage::FileSystem.new('public', prefix: 'uploads/store'),
}

Shrine.plugin :activerecord
Shrine.plugin :remove_attachment
Shrine.plugin :delete_raw
Shrine.plugin :cached_attachment_data # for forms
```

**uploader**

```
require 'image_processing/mini_magick'
class ImageUploader < Shrine
  MAX_IMAGE_SIZE_MB = 5
  include ImageProcessing::MiniMagick

  plugin :determine_mime_type
  plugin :remove_attachment
  plugin :store_dimensions
  plugin :validation_helpers
  plugin :processing
  plugin :versions
  plugin(:default_url) { |_|  '/img/preview-not-available.jpg' }

  Attacher.validate do
    validate_max_size MAX_IMAGE_SIZE_MB.megabytes, message: "is too large (max is #{MAX_IMAGE_SIZE_MB} MB)"
    validate_mime_type_inclusion %w[image/jpeg image/jpg image/png image/gif]
  end

  process(:store) do |io|
    original = io.download

    size_1500 = resize_to_limit!(original, 1500, 600)
    size_500 = resize_to_limit(size_1500,  500, 500)
    size_300 = resize_to_limit(size_500,  300, 300)

    {original: size_1500, medium: size_500, thumb: size_300 }
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi - looks like you've been around Stack overflow for  while, so you should be aware that we expect you to have a go at it yourself first then come to us with a bug you've found ;) what have you tried to get the preview working? what do you observe happening instead? that kind of thing ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to show PDF previews, you'll need to generate them on the server side. In that case it's best to use [direct uploads](http://shrinerb.com/rdoc/classes/Shrine/Plugins/UploadEndpoint.html) (see the [demo](https://github.com/janko-m/shrine/blob/master/demo/assets/js/app.js) for an example of a client side implementation).

You can then generate PDFs preview on direct upload:

```
# config/initializers/shrine.rb
Shrine.plugin :determine_mime_type

# app/models/image_uploader.rb
class ImageUploader < Shrine
  plugin :processing
  plugin :versions

  process(:upload) do |io, context|
    if Shrine.determine_mime_type(io) == "application/pdf"
      preview = Tempfile.new(["shrine-pdf-preview", ".pdf"], binmode: true)
      begin
        IO.popen *%W[mutool draw -F png -o - #{io.path} 1], "rb" do |command|
          IO.copy_stream(command, preview)
        end
      rescue Errno::ENOENT
        fail "mutool is not installed"
      end

      preview.open # flush & rewind
    end

    versions = { original: io }
    versions[:preview] = preview if preview && preview.size > 0
    versions
  end
end
```

- the `upload_endpoint` sets the `:upload` processing action, so that's the meaning of `process(:upload)`
- we use `rb` for `IO.popen` so that Ruby uses binary encoding, which is more safe and cross-platform
- `Kernel#spawn` and any methods that use `spawn` (`system`, `IO.popen` etc.) will raise `Errno::ENOENT` when shell command was not found
- we use `*%W[]` instead of just `""` so that Ruby avoids the shell (and with that any possible shell escaping issues) and passes the command directly to the OS
- we check whether the `preview` file is nonempty because it will be empty in case the `mutool` command failed (in this case we probably want to fall back to not displaying a preview)

The result of the POST request to the `upload_endpoint` will now contain the uploaded file ID of the preview, which you can use to generate the URL to the preview. In your case that would be `"/uploads/cache" + id`.

Note that this means you'll have to slightly modify the processing code that is called when cached file is promoted to permanent storage. In the `process(:store) do |io, context|` block the `io` will now be a hash of versions, so you can access the original cached file via `io[:original]`. And be sure to also include the preview file in the result of that block, as you'll likely want to keep it.

```
process(:store) do |io, context|
  original = io[:original].download

  # processing...

  versions = io.dup
  versions[:small] = small
  versions[:medium] = medium
  # ...
  versions
end
```